# Does the decimal portion of $n\log_3 2$ cover all irrational numbers between 0 and 1 repeatedly, where n is all positive integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does the decimal portion of $n\log_3 2$ include all irrational numbers between 0 and 1 repeatedly, where $n$ is all positive integers?

Oddly enough I ran into this question while fooling around with the Collatz Conjecture.

Lacking an answer, directions as to how to find an answer (what to read up on) would be useful.

---

Decimal Portion: integer portion → `3 | .141592653` ← decimal portion

repeatedly: cycling through again and again

---

As a follow-up question, and perhaps the one I should have initially asked:

Would the decimal portion of $n\log_3 2$ include all numbers in the decimal portion of $log_3(n + 1/2)$? (again, n representing all positive integers)

Comment: No. You only obtain countably many numbers this way, but there are uncountably many rationals between 0 and 1.

Comment: It contains all *finite* strings of digits infinitely often.  A consequence of the fact that $\log_3 2$ is irrational.

Comment: @Casey: Take any nummber $a$ in the unit interval, irrational or rational. Given any $\epsilon>0$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that the fractional part of $\log_3 2$ is at distance less than $\epsilon$ from $a$.

Comment: @GEdgar Are you certain that the one follows from the other?  That seems decidedly non-trivial...

Comment: The fractional part of $n\log_3 2$ is probably dense in $[0,1)$. Perhaps this suffices for your needs?

Comment: @Steven: Yes. And each finite string appears asymptotically as often as every other of the same length.

Comment: @Didier I think that's the definition of a normal number. As far as I know, proving a number is normal is ridiculously hard.

Comment: @chris Nope. You are confusing (i) the expansion of a single number and (ii) the sequence of iterates of a number by a transformation (here the rotation by $\log_32$ on the unit circle). I agree that finding normal numbers (case (i)) may be difficult (that is, unless one relies on basic probabilistic techniques), but (ii) is a different, easier, story.

Comment: Difference between density of fractional part of $n\log_3 2$ compared to fractional part of $10^n\log_3 2$

Comment: For the fact that the fractional part of $n a$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ when $a$ is irrational, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: again, note that it's $n a$, not $10^n a$.

Comment: Oops. I read GEdgar's comment too quickly. Sorry about that. Thanks for pointing it out, Robert.

Comment: @GEdgar The number 0.101001000100001... is irrational but clearly does not contain all finite strings of digits. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Ronald:  call that number $x$.  No, $x$ does not contain all finite strings, but the collection of all $n x$ does.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, understood.

Comment: Mea culpa on my mental slip there - I'd forgotten the equidistribution theorem, which certainly makes it easy.

Comment: @Didier Ah thank you. I had missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\{\mbox{decimal portion of } n\log_3 2\; |\;  n \mbox{ is a positive integer}\}$, and $B=\{a\in[0,1]\;|\;a \mbox{ is irrational}\}$. Set $A$ is countable (there is a trivial one to one correspondence between $A$ and set of natural numbers), but $B$ is uncountable. So $B\nsubseteq A$. But obviously $A\subset B$.

Comment: As for the second question, it doesn't have this problem. And to be clear, I assume you mean if $$A=\{n\log_3 2-\lfloor{n\log_3 2}\rfloor: n\in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}\},$$ and $$B=\{ \log_3(n+\frac12)- \lfloor\log_3(n+\frac12\rfloor: n\in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}\},$$ then is it true that $A\subseteq B$?

Answer (score 1):

Your follow-up question is unclear. I think you are asking whether every fractional part of $\log_3(n+(1/2))$ is also the fractional part of $m\log_32$ for some $m$. In fact, the fractional part of $\log_3(n+(1/2))$ is *never* the fractional part of $m\log_32$ for *any* $m$. If it were, it would mean that $$m\log_32-\log_3(n+(1/2))$$ is an integer. But this is $\log_3(2^{m+1}/(2n+1))$, which can't be an integer, since $2^{m+1}/(2n+1)$ can't be a power of 3.

Comment: It can be a negative power of 3, can' it be?

Comment: Only if $m=-1$, and the question referred to positive values.

Comment: you're right. I didn't notice that.